# A vector field with an integrating factor has a first integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields, integrating-factor

I have a problem that I don't know how to solve it, It says:

Let $X=(f,g)\in \mathcal C^1(\mathbb{R})^2$ be a vector field and consider the system $\dot x = f(x,y), \; \dot y = g(x,y) $. If the system has an integrating factor $\mu(x,y) $, prove that $X$ has a first integral $H(x,y)$.

---

The hints and definitions that I have are:

- $\mu(x,y) $ is a integrating factor iff $\mu(x,y)\neq 0, \; \forall
     (x,y)$ and $div (\mu X)=0 $
- If $H$ is a first integral of $X$, then $DH(x,y)X(x,y)=0$
- If $divX=0$, then $X$ has a first integral (with some conditions of
  the domain I think, but it works in this problem)

With all of this, we know that $\mu  X$ has a first integral $\tilde H$, and I think I should prove that $\frac 1\mu \tilde H$ is the first integral of $X$ that I'm looking for.

Hence, I'm trying to prove that $D\left(\frac 1\mu \tilde H \right)(x,y)X(x,y)=0$, using that $D\tilde H(x,y) (\mu X)(x,y) =0$ and $div(\mu X)=0 $

On the one hand,

$$ div (\mu X)=\mu \;div X + \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial x} f+\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial y} g=0 $$

On the other hand,

$$D\left(\frac 1\mu \tilde H \right)(x,y)X(x,y)=-\frac1{\mu^2}\tilde H \left(\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial x} f+\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial y} g\right)+D\tilde H\cdot X = \frac 1\mu div X \cdot \tilde H$$

amd I'm not sure how I can continue, or if I'm in the correct way.

Any help is welcome!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it's easier. If $\mu X$ has a first integral $H$, then

$$0=DH(x, y) (\mu X)(xy) =\mu DH(x,y)X(x,y)$$

so $H$ is a first integral of $X$.

Am I right?
Thanks